# Не работает lambda функция при печати случайной буквы из списка

Tags: python, случайные-числа, lambda

```
import random
print(lambda upletters: (random.choice(['Q','W','E','R','T','Y','U','I','O','P','A','S','D','F','G','H','J','K','L','Z','X','C','V','B','N','M'])))
```

Возможно синтаксис не корректен. Помогите разобраться.

Comment: Лямбду никто не вызывает, всё правильно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы хотите **использовать** лямбду в точке объявления,  именовать её не надо. Более того, код вида

```
lambda upletters : ...
```

объявляет лямбду с параметром `upletters`. Для использования лямбды "на месте" её нужно **вызвать** следующим образом:

```
(lambda : ...)()
```

Таким образом, корректный код в данном случае имеет следующий вид:

```
import random
print( (lambda : (random.choice(['Q','W']))) () )
```

(Массив сократил для улучшения понимания конструкции.)

Comment: Благодарю. Разобрался.

Answer (score 2):

О  вопросе:

- код не выбрасывает SyntaxError, то есть синтаксис корректен. Достаточно запустить код в вопросе, чтобы это увидеть
- в коде нет явного словаря, поэтому не ясно к чему заголовок *"Не работает lambda функция в словаре"* относился
- выражение с `lambda` также как и `def` cоздаёт функцию, но не вызывает её
- `upletters` -- это агрумент функции в коде (который никак не используется)
- `lambda` здесь не нужна, код можно переписать как:

  ```
  import random
  print(random.choice('QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM'))
  ```

  или для ясности:

  ```
  import random
  import string
  print(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase))
  ```

Назначение `lambda` создание *анонимных* функций. Если хочется вызывать код по *имени*, то следует `def` использовать:

```
import random
import string

def random_letter(letters=string.ascii_uppercase):
    """Select a random letter from *letters*."""
    return random.choice(letters)

print(random_letter())
```

Функции являются полноценными объектами в Питоне: им можно дать имя, их можно передавать в качестве параметров в другие функции (такие как `print()`) и тд:

- `random_letter` (без скобочек) возвращает саму функцию (объект)
- `random_letter()` (со скобками) вызывает функцию (и возвращает букву в данном случае, то есть выражение возвращает строку).

Если хочется передать функцию как выражение (без имени), например, в другую функцию `f()`, то можно `functools.partial()` использовать, чтобы облегчить интроспекцию:

```
f(functools.partial(random.choice, string.ascii_uppercase))
# instead of `f(lambda: random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase))`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
upletters = lambda : (random.choice(['Q','W','E','R','T','Y','U','I','O','P','A','S','D','F','G','H','J','K','L','Z','X','C','V','B','N','M']))
print(upletters())
```

lambda возвращает функцию